# How to split the output from ls -l to display in proper formate

Tags: bash, shell

i am writing a bash script which formats output from ls-l to look like this

```
Owner Group Other Filename
----- ----- ----- --------
rwx   rwx    rwx   myDIR1
rwx   r-x    --x   myDIR2
Links: 4 Owner: unx510 Group: users Size: 229 Modified: Feb 22 2015
```

My script is called pathDisplay and a directory path is passed as an argument to it. For e.g.

```
=>bash ./pathDisplay /home
```

I don't know how to split the output of ls -l command. This is what i have so far:

```
echo "Owner   Group   Other   Filename"
echo "-----   -----   -----   --------"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
ls -l $1 | grep '^d' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1,9 |  
while read line                                                                                                         
do
userPermissions=$(cut -b 2-4)
groupPermissions=$(cut -b 5-7)
otherPermissions=$(cut -b 8-10)
dirName=$(cut -b 11-)
echo -n "$userPermissions   $groupPermission   $otherPermission  $dirName"
stat -c "links:%h, owner:%U, group:%G, size:%B, modified:%y" "$dirName"
done
```

This is what i am getting

```
Owner   Group   Other   Filename
-----   -----   -----   --------
rwx        stat: missing operand
```

Comment: you *can* process `ls` for display purposes (but for nothing else please) from what i can see `tr` deleted all spaces that's why `cut` fails. i recommend to make a loop over plain file names and do everything else with only `stat`

Comment: I'm assuming you want to `cut` out portions of the `${line}` variable but I see no reference to `${line}` in the `cut` commands; your `echo -n` is missing the trailing `s` for the group/other variables

Answer (score 0):

safest way to process file names is

```
for line in "$@"
  do
    test -e "$line" || continue
    stat "$line"
done
```

not sure if you want to stat parent or subdir, but you can loop over children like this (trailing `/` will match directories only)

```
echo Owner$'\t'Group$'\t'Other$'\t'Filename
echo -----$'\t'-----$'\t'-----$'\t'--------

for line in "$@"
  do
    test -e "$line" || continue
    for file in "$line"/*/ "$line"/.*/
      do
        file="${file%/}"
        [ -e "$file" ] && [ "${file##*/}" != "." ] && [ "${file##*/}" != ".." ] || continue
        perm=$(stat -c%A "$file")
        user=${perm:1:3}
        group=${perm:4:3}
        other=${perm:7:3}

        size=$(du -Lhd0 "$file" | cut -f1)
        printf -v mtime '%(%b %d %Y)T' $(stat -c%Y "$file")

        printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' $user $group $other "${file##*/}"
        stat -c "links: %h, owner: %U, group: %G, size: $size, modified: $mtime" "$file" 

    done
done
```

Comment: you can move the *size + mtime + stat* (for *$line*) into outer loop (between 1st and 2nd *done*)